# Negative Input DC-DC power supply

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, telecommunications

I have a requirement of DC DC power supply where the input voltage is -48VDC and output voltage : +5V and -5V with output current 4A and 3A. Is it correct to use a DC DC power supply of more than 35W and give the inputs as inverted polarity?

Thanking in advance

Comment: If the SPSU is *designed for negative input* that is OK (but check wthere the outputs can each deliver the required current).

Comment: Use a: "isolated DC/DC converter". With those, a transformer is used and the input is not connected to the output. You may not give the input an inverted voltage.

Comment: No such thing as inverted polarity. -48 is the same as +48.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen The supply that I'm planning to use does not mention any negative input voltage range. The current rating is the required range.

Comment: @Jot, Can I use a non isolated DC/DC converter of required specification.

Comment: @Misunderstood "No such thing as inverted polarity. -48 is the same as +48" -> you certainly live up to your name.

Comment: @Manisha: *only* if it explcitly allows a negative input voltage.

Comment: A non isolated DC/DC converter with negative input does exist, for example the LT8709. I have not seen a complete module that can do that. The is no good reason for such a module, because with a isolated DC/DC converter you can make any input and any output pin the ground level. There is no advantage for a non isolated DC/DC converter.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen If I have a 48V source powering both a -48V telephone system and +48V LED Lighting, is that source -48 or +48?